# How to redirect to /Account/Login when calling an Action Method with Authorize attribute in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a Home Controller marked with Authorize attribute that contains an Index action method. I also have an Account controller with Login method. When I access /Home/Index, I only see a blank page, I was expecting it to redirect to /Account/Login. The book I am reading states that by default, it redirects to /Account/Login but it does not redirect there (the URL on browser still the same).

I tried this from an empty ASP.NET Core project, adding in what I think I only need for testing this out. Do I need to add something else? I tried the default ASP.NET Core Application with Individual User Accounts and it redirects to /Account/Login but I cannot see anywhere that this was explicitly set up so I am not sure why its working for the default sample project and not on my initially empty project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stuff is all handled by ASP.NET Core Identity in the project template. You can find more details about how that's setup here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=vs0.

It's the call to `UseIdentity` on the `IApplicationBuilder` interface that sets up the redirect for you.